# Redirect the user if he requested direct .php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

using .htaccess file, I want the user to be directed to another URL if he requested a .php file directly in the browser

for example: if the user requested example.com/test.php is should redirect him to example.com/redirectionEndpoint.

here are the apache server configurations that I'm using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app01
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/app01
    <Directory /var/www/public_html/app01>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/dev01-access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/dev01-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

and that is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: What did you attempt ? (show the .htaccess file you created)

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect from test.php to redirectionEndpoint.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/test\.php\?(?:\S+)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /redirectionEndpoint? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules to rewrite to test.php.
RewriteRule ^redirectionEndpoint/?$ test.php [NC,L]

##For any other non-existing page should go to index.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: @AliBeshir, kindly do provide more info here. Like which sample url you are hitting and what error you are getting in browser?

Comment: @AliBeshir, could you please do let me know more above asked details here, thank you.